# No internet when installing a new ubuntu from an USB key

Tags: networking, system-installation

If I install a new Ubuntu on my computer, it's impossible to activate the internet connection.
After a while the network card goes to "Off".

If I choose to install Ubuntu it's impossible to open the network settings because no option is proposed to configure the network. It try only through DHCP and when it fails the interfaces go Off. If you put it On again, it try then goes Off again. Impossible to setup the internet.

If I choose to try Ubuntu instead of install it, the network works, I have to open the network settings and then put the right IP/mask, gateway and DNS. After that I can install without problems, but I have to choose "Try" instead of "Install" then launch the installer manually.

To me that is a bug of the installer, it should propose to configure the network following the customer need!

Maybe I've missing something, so are there some ways to configure the network while installing Ubuntu without go through "Try Ubuntu" ?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify exactly what you are turning "On" and how you are doing that. Please edit your question to add the complete output of `sudo lshw -class network` and the complete output of `ip a`, both of the installed system that lacks network connectivity.

Comment: Start the installer (standard), choose "Install Ubuntu", when you arrive where you choose how to install it the option to automatically download the updates is inactive because the network has no DHCP and the system was unable to set up the network. Now try to setup the network, you can't because there is no option to enter the IP address. The network cards in the upper right icon are disabled and if you turn them On, they turn Off again automatically after a timeout.